# ¿Como hacer que un label de un frame pase a otro label pero de diferente frame?

Tags: java, jframe

Mi duda es que piden que al buscar en información en la base de datos en el primer label capturara cierta información y también en unos textfield capturara cierta informacion pero al dar click al textfield abrirá otra ventana y en esa ventana contendrá labels que también tendrá la misma información del label de la otra ventana 
Esto es lo que llevo

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

/**
 *
 * @author Hp
 */
public class Pestaña_1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Examen2 Ex=new Examen2();
ConexionMySQL mysql=new ConexionMySQL();
    /**
     * Creates new form Pestaña_1
     */

```
public Pestaña_1() {
    initComponents();
    MA=Ex.jLabel2;
}
```

/*public void igualdad(String val){
     String sSQL;
        String clavematerias = null, nombre = null, creditos = null, horasC = null, horasT = null, horasL = null, programaeducativo = null;
        Connection cn = mysql.conectar();
        sSQL ="SELECT * FROM asignaciones.tbl_materias";
        String Ss=Ex.jLabel2.getText();
        MA.setText(Ss);
}*/
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // 
    private void initComponents() {

```
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    MA = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    CbHE = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    CbHS = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    Cbdia = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    CbGrupo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NEtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    BtBuscar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    BtAM = new javax.swing.JButton();
    CbSalon = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Mecatronica");

    jLabel2.setText("/");

    jLabel4.setText("/");

    jLabel6.setText("Grupo:");

    jLabel7.setText("Dia:");

    jLabel8.setText("Hora Entrada:");

    jLabel9.setText("Hora Salida:");

    CbHE.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00" }));

    CbHS.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00" }));

    Cbdia.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves ", "Viernes" }));

    CbGrupo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "531", "532", "533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538" }));

    jLabel10.setText("Num. Empleado");

    BtBuscar.setText("Buscar");

    jLabel12.setText("Salon");

    BtAM.setText("Asignar Materia");

    CbSalon.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "A04", "A14", "A24", "A34" }));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(MA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(jLabel12))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(CbGrupo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(Cbdia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(NEtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(CbSalon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(CbHS, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, 68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(CbHE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(BtBuscar)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(BtAM)))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(MA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(CbGrupo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(Cbdia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                .addComponent(NEtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(BtBuscar)
                        .addComponent(BtAM))
                    .addGap(102, 102, 102))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(CbHE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addComponent(CbHS, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel12)
                        .addComponent(CbSalon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(69, 69, 69))))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(129, 129, 129))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pestaña_1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pestaña_1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pestaña_1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Pestaña_1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Pestaña_1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton BtAM;
private javax.swing.JButton BtBuscar;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> CbGrupo;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> CbHE;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> CbHS;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> CbSalon;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> Cbdia;
public javax.swing.JLabel MA;
private javax.swing.JTextField NEtext;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

```
/*
```

* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Examen2;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Hp
 */
public class Examen2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ConexionMySQL mysql = new ConexionMySQL();
    /**
     * Creates new form Pestaña_2
     */
    public Examen2() {
        initComponents();
    }

```
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    CMtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    HCtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    HLtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    HTtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnBuscar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Clave Materia:");

    jLabel3.setText("HC:");

    HCtext.setEditable(false);
    HCtext.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            HCtextMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setText("HL:");

    HLtext.setEditable(false);
    HLtext.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            HLtextMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setText("HT:");

    HTtext.setEditable(false);
    HTtext.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            HTtextMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    btnBuscar.setText("Buscar");
    btnBuscar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnBuscarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 146, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(132, 132, 132)
                    .addComponent(btnGuardar))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(CMtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(HCtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(HLtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(HTtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(96, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(CMtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnBuscar))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(HCtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(HLtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(HTtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addComponent(btnGuardar))
            .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void HCtextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    Pestaña_1 i = new Pestaña_1();
    String BS = CMtext.getText();
    i.show();
```

i.MA=jLabel2;        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

```
private void HLtextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    Pestaña_1 i = new Pestaña_1();
    i.show();
    /*String sSQL;
    String clavematerias = null, nombre = null, creditos = null, horasC = null, horasT = null, horasL = null, programaeducativo = null;
    Connection cn = mysql.conectar();
    sSQL ="SELECT * FROM asignaciones.tbl_materias";*/

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void HTtextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    Pestaña_1 i = new Pestaña_1();
    i.show();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Pestaña_1 Pe = new Pestaña_1();
    String sSQL;
    String clavematerias = null, nombre = null, creditos = null, horasC = null, horasT = null, horasL = null, programaeducativo = null;
    String BS = CMtext.getText();


    Connection cn = mysql.conectar();
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_materias Where clavematerias= " + BS;

    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);
        while (rs.next()) {
            clavematerias = rs.getString("clavematerias");
            nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
            creditos = rs.getString("creditos");
            horasC = rs.getString("horasC");
            horasT = rs.getString("horasT");
            horasL = rs.getString("horasL");
            programaeducativo = rs.getString("programaeducativo");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }

    jLabel2.setText(programaeducativo);
    HCtext.setText(horasC);
    HTtext.setText(horasT);
    HLtext.setText(horasL);
    //Pe.MA=jLabel2;
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Examen2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Examen2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Examen2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Examen2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Examen2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField CMtext;
private javax.swing.JTextField HCtext;
private javax.swing.JTextField HLtext;
private javax.swing.JTextField HTtext;
private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Por mas que trato de no me quiere dar esa imfornacion